# What exactly is the "wid" argument in the ezANOVA function in the R package "ez"?

Tags: r, anova

I'm very new to all this, and I am testing different ways to perform a two-way type III ANOVA on my data.

- I have tried `anova()` from the `stats` package, after fitting a linear regression with `lm()`;
- I have tried `Anova()` from the `car` package, using the same linear regression (and this gives me the same result as `anova()` when I use `type="II"` - I thought `anova()` used type I SS by default?).
- And I am now trying to use `ezANOVA()` from the `ez` package.

With this last one, I can't understand what the `wid=.()` argument is (even reading the help), and as it is not optional, I can't leave it blank. What I am trying to use is as follows, with its result:

```
> attach(data)
> library("ez")
> ezANOVA(data=data, dv=.(AG.DW), wid=.(), within=.(Genotype, Treatment), type=3)
Warning: Converting "" to factor for ANOVA.
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

Is this the right script? What is `wid` and what should I fill it with?

Concerning my data, the columns `Genotype` and `Treatment` are my two factors, and I want to see if there is an interaction when looking at the aboveground dry weight of my plants (column `AG.DW`). My data is balanced.

I am sorry if information is missing or inaccurate here: this is my first contribution here, and I am only discovering statistics at the moment (and I can't see how to join my data file).

Comment: Note that you will need the [development version](https://github.com/mike-lawrence/ez) of `ez` to perform type 3 ANOVAs. And you need to set the appropriate contrasts: `options(contrasts=c('contr.sum','contr.poly'))`

Comment: Thanks Henrik. The version I have (3.0-1) shows in it's help page that type=3 is available (but the results are the same as a type 1 or 2...).
How do I know what contrasts are appropriate in my case?

Comment: Succesfully running a Type 3 ANOVA in `ez` involves two steps. At first, the current version of `ez` [suffers a bug that the type 3 ANOVA is not calculated correctly](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ez4r/I7FzfOTU5Fo/overview). You will need to download the development version (if your data is unbalanced type 2 and type 3 give different results). Second, if you have the correct version you need to run the above mentioned command before running `ezANOVA` with type = 3.

Comment: Interestingly, with the 3.0-1 version of ez, the result of a type 3 ANOVA without contrasts is the same as a type 3 ANOVA with contrasts using:
`> Anova(lm(AG.DW~Genotype*Treatment, contrasts=list(Genotype=contr.sum, Treatment=contr.sum)), type=3)`

What do you think this is?

Answer (score 1):

First off, are you familiar with R's help system? Typing `?ezANOVA` will bring up the documentation for that function, where you can read that the `wid` argument is a:

> .() object specifying the column in data that contains the variable specifying the case/Ss identifier.

Based on how you've specified your model so far, your design seems to be a within-subjects one, where each subject (is this a plot/plant/area?) is assigned to each of the levels of Genotype and Treatment. Your `wid` argument would then be the column that identifies the individual plant/plot, eg. `wid=.(plant.number)`.

If none of this seems to match up with your experimental design, then it may be that one or both of your Genotype and Treatment factors are actually *between-subjects* variables, and you should be including them in the `between = .()` argument instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Now I understand the difference between vs within, and my experiment is actually a between-subject design: I have 5 genotypes, each one tested in 3 different treatments, with 5 replicates, so a total of 75 plants.
Still, I don't understand what I should include in "wid"... Is it just a sequence of numbers, from 1 to 75, so each plant has it's own number? If this is the case, what is it for? It doesn't influence the calculations at all, does it?